# SQL Database to Listview

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to populate a ListView from a database file the app builds, I appreciate this may have been covered a few times but I can't find an answer unique to what I need, I have written this code but the app always forces to close when it runs

```
public void ViewData()
{
    vdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Cursor cursor = mydb.getAllRows();
            String[] fromfieldnames = new String[] {DatabaseHelper.COL_1, DatabaseHelper.COL_2, DatabaseHelper.COL_3, DatabaseHelper.COL_4};
            int[] toviewids = new int[] {R.id.textone, R.id.texttwo, R.id.textthree, R.id.textfour};
            SimpleCursorAdapter mycursoradapter;
            mycursoradapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.listtext, cursor, fromfieldnames, toviewids, 0);
            listView.setAdapter(mycursoradapter);

        }
    });
}
```

and here is my helper code

```
public Cursor getAllRows()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String where = null;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, ALL_KEYS);
    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

I think I have everything right but doesn't seem to work

Thanks in advance
M.

Sorry here is a drop from the error LogCat

```
08-10 11:07:09.474: E/memtrack(32373): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
08-10 11:07:09.475: E/android.os.Debug(32373): failed to load memtrack module: -2
08-10 11:07:12.411: E/memtrack(32418): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
08-10 11:07:12.411: E/android.os.Debug(32418): failed to load memtrack module: -2
08-10 11:07:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(32432): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-10 11:07:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(32432): Process: com.boltgames.dev.cricketone, PID: 32432
08-10 11:07:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(32432): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 4 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
08-10 11:07:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(32432):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bind(SQLiteProgram.java:212)
08-10 11:07:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(32432):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:166)
08-10 11:07:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(32432):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
08-10 11:07:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(32432):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
08-10 11:07:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(32432):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
08-10 11:07:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(32432):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
08-10 11:07:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(32432):    at com.boltgames.dev.cricketlife.DatabaseHelper.getAllRows(DatabaseHelper.java:68)
08-10 11:07:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(32432):    at com.boltgames.dev.cricketlife.Developer$2.onClick(Developer.java:107)
08-10 11:07:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(32432):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
08-10 11:07:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(32432):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
08-10 11:07:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(32432):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-10 11:07:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(32432):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-10 11:07:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(32432):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-10 11:07:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(32432):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
08-10 11:07:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(32432):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-10 11:07:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(32432):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-10 11:07:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(32432):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
08-10 11:07:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(32432):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
08-10 11:07:23.403: E/BufferQueueProducer(608): [com.boltgames.dev.cricketone/com.boltgames.dev.cricketlife.Developer] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
08-10 11:07:23.403: E/EGL_emulation(32432): tid 32451: swapBuffers(286): error 0x3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
08-10 11:07:23.403: A/OpenGLRenderer(32432): Encountered EGL error 12291 EGL_BAD_ALLOC during rendering
08-10 11:07:23.403: A/libc(32432): Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xb749a62c in tid 32451 (RenderThread)
08-10 11:07:23.454: E/DEBUG(87): unexpected waitpid response: n=32451, status=00000009
08-10 11:07:23.454: E/DEBUG(87): tid exited before attach completed: tid 32451
```

Comment: stack trace? whats on the logcat?

Comment: sorry il link that now

Comment: This `String where = null;` is **useless**. And this `, ALL_KEYS);` should be `, null);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your query

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
```

The second argument of `rawQuery` is for arguments that will be bound to placeholders (`?`) in the SQL string. Your SQL string has none of these placeholders, so you should not be supplying any arguments to bind. For example, If you wanted to make this query...

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 > 0"
```

...you would call it like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_1 + " > ?";
String sqlArgs = new String[] {Integer.valueOf(0)}; // binds to ?
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, sqlArgs);
```